# How to use add elements to a matrix?

Tags: netlogo

I want to add multiple items from one list to another list, that is organized in one big list, like a matrix.

```
let targetlists (list firstlist seccondlist thirdlist)
```

So in my double while loop, I added this code;

```
set (item x targetlists) lput (item y sourcelist) (item x targetlists)
```

Sadly it gives me the following error:

> This isn't something you can use "set" on.

I found out that it has to do with how I select the target list, as the following code does work, but doesn't do what I want:

```
set firstlist lput (item y sourcelist) firstlist
```

Comment: What is a `double` in that context? Maybe it's due to my lack of knowledge concerning netlogo but I don't understand your question.

Comment: some confusing language from me :p, i mean i have a while loop inside another while loop.

Comment: you need `replace-item` rather than `set` to edit a value in an arbitrary position of a list (or `insert-item` if you are putting a value into the middle somewhere rather than changing an existing value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JenB is right that, in general, you use `replace-item`. However, replacing your `while` loops with [`map`](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#map) will be much more effective.

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do, but it looks like you're trying to put the elements of `sourcelist` onto the end of the lists in `targetlists`. Even if that's not what you're doing, this should point you in the right direction:

```
set targetlists (map [ [ source-item target-row ] ->
  lput source-item target-row
] sourcelist targetlists)
```

This will iterate through the items of `sourcelist` and `targetlists` together, calling `lput` on the pairs.

Also, there's a handy shortcut where, if a reporter already does what you want, you can pass it directly to `map`. So you can condense this to:

```
set targetlists (map lput sourcelist targetlists)
```

Now, given that you mentioned nested `while`s and you're indexing into the two lists with two different indices, you might be trying to put the entire contents of `sourcelist` onto the ends of each of the `targetlists`. If that's the case, you can just do

```
set targetlists map [ l -> (sentence l sourcelist) ] targetlists
```

If I'm totally off, and you're trying to do something completely different, just let me know in the comments and I'll update my answer.